# react-draft-wysiwyg editor value is causing content-security-policy issue because of inline style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, content-security-policy, react-draft-wysiwyg

how to fix content-security-policy issue which is caused by react-draft-wysiwyg editor value which have inline style in it after deploy and styles are not applied to it , because of the issue. how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the issue depends on what CSP said in the violation message. Can be 3 kinds of inline styles and each has its own specifics.

The easiest way is to find where the React application publishes the CSP (it should be a meta tag) and add `'unsafe-inline'` to the `style-src` directive.
This allows you to fix the problem with all three types of inline styles.

Most likely the meta tag with CSP is published by a plugin like `react-static-plugin-csp-meta-tags`, `react-csp` or `react-helmet`. Find it out and add `'unsafe-inline'` to the `style-src` directive, but not to the `default-src` because in case of absent `script-src` this will allow execution inline scripts which is not safe.

Some plugins, for instance `react-static-plugin-csp-meta-tags`, allows to hashe inline styles like `<style>...</style>`. In this case you can avoid using `'unsafe-inline'` and use a `'hash-value'` if this `<style>` block is not changed time to time.